# Pass CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to target_compile_options

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags

I'm attempting to pass all the original `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` like an argument to `target_compile_options` function.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra)

# I'd wish this target_compile_options
target_compile_options(my_target INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

This gives me an error:

```
g++.exe: error:  -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra: No such file or directory
```

I know a simple solution is:

```
target_compile_options(my_target INTERFACE -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra)
```

But I'd want to keep the original `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)`, would it be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` expects a single string (parameters are separated by spaces) while `target_compile_options` uses a [list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists) (parameters are separated by semicolons).

As a quick hack, you could try separating all spaces by semicolons using the [`string`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/string.html) command:

```
 # this will probably break if you omit the "s
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra")

string(REPLACE " " ";" REPLACED_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
target_compile_options(my_target INTERFACE ${REPLACED_FLAGS})
```

Note that in the real world, you would never want to both set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` *and* set the `target_compile_options` at the same time. You should stick with one approach (in my experience `target_compile_options` is less likely to cause trouble in the long run) and use the correct string separators for that throughout.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I know that and they're in different projects but this question came to my mind and I couldn't help trying to resolve it.