# CMake for multiple targets

Tags: cmake, linker, cross-compiling, cmakelists-options

[enter image description here][1]Could You please help me writing my CMakeLists.txt file for embedded system (ARM MCU) using Eclipse IDE? I have two targets (executables): *test.elf*, *test_boot.elf*.

```
project(test C ASM)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf
${DRIVERS_DIR}/hal_clkctr.c
${DRIVERS_DIR}/hal_ioctr.c
source/startup_ELIOT01.s
source/system_ELIOT01.c
source/main.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/can.c  
${SYSTEM_DIR}/gpio.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/i2c.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/mutex.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/onewire.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/sdcard.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/spi.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/sysclk.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/systick.c  
${SYSTEM_DIR}/uart.c
${MODULES_DIR}/adc.c
${MODULES_DIR}/dac.c
${MODULES_DIR}/ds18b20.c
${MODULES_DIR}/ioexpander.c
${MODULES_DIR}/powermonitor.c
${MODULES_DIR}/rtc.c
${TESTS_DIR}/memtest.c
${TESTS_DIR}/testcmd.c
${TESTS_DIR}/tests.c
${APPLICATION_DIR}/print.c
${APPLICATION_DIR}/utils_syscalls.c
```

)

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf
${DRIVERS_DIR}/hal_clkctr.c
${DRIVERS_DIR}/hal_ioctr.c
source/startup_ELIOT01.s
source/system_ELIOT01.c
source/main_boot.c
${SYSTEM_DIR}/sysclk.c 
${SYSTEM_DIR}/uart.c
${APPLICATION_DIR}/print.c
```

)

I also have two linker files (test.ld and boot.ld). **And i wonder how is it possible to set different linkers for my executables?** Because `set_target_property` results in errors like "Undefined reference to..." in startup file. But i'm sure that startup is fine because i've built the project with one *test.elf* executable many times. Below is the second part of my CMakeLists.txt. As you can see, CMake creates *boot.elf* linking *test.ld* but not *boot.ld* file. The same thing happens with *.map* file.

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/test.ld -D__USE_CMSIS")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -g3 -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map")

add_custom_command( 
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf > ${PROJECT_NAME}.dis
    COMMENT "[post] Create disassemble file ${PROJECT_NAME}.dis"
)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf > ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.dis
    COMMENT "[post] Create disassemble file ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.dis"
)
```

P.S. By the way, `add_custom_command` works fine for both targets...

Dear Armandas, here it is..
Code written by Your advice:

```
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/test.ld -D__USE_CMSIS
)

target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/boot.ld -D__USE_CMSIS
)

#SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/boot.ld -D__USE_CMSIS")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -g3 -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.map")

add_custom_command( 
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf > ${PROJECT_NAME}.dis
    COMMENT "[post] Create disassemble file ${PROJECT_NAME}.dis"
)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJDUMP} -D ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.elf > ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.dis
    COMMENT "[post] Create disassemble file ${PROJECT_NAME}_boot.dis"
)
```

It has following errors:

```
d:/eliot01-sdk/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: address 0x33a0 of test_boot.elf section `.text' is not within region 'FLASH'
d:/eliot01-sdk/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: test_boot.elf section '.ARM.extab' will not fit in region 'FLASH'
d:/eliot01-sdk/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: address 0x33a0 of test_boot.elf section '.text' is not within region 'FLASH'
d:/eliot01-sdk/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region 'FLASH' overflowed by 4024415372 bytes
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\test_boot.elf.dir\build.make:207: test_boot.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:110: CMakeFiles/test_boot.elf.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

And the same errors for test.elf executable

Comment: I suspect there may be an issue in your linker script.

Comment: Linker is gcc_arm.ld "GNU Linker Script for Cortex-M based device" of 21 May, 2019...

Comment: So did you remove the `-T` from `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` before testing the `PS` part? Did you make sure that `boot.ld` actually has no errors? Please post the verbose output of compilation (`make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --verbose`). Your question is how to use the linker script, it is being used, that's it.  `region 'FLASH' overflowed by 4024415372 bytes` weeeell, that's a lot of bytes

Comment: Dear KamilCuk, as i stated, both linkers (`test.ld` and `boot.ld`) work fine when using them for one executable (`test.elf` and `boot.elf` respectively). Problems occur when trying to build both executables simultaneously. And problem is in `CMakeLists.txt`, i suppose

Answer (score 1):

Use [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html):

```
target_link_options(${project_name}.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/test.ld
)

target_link_options(${project_name}_boot.elf
    PRIVATE
        -T${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${DEVICE_DIR}/boot.ld
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.. Thank You for Your answear, i stated the problem when using Your method in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I've found solution here: [Pass CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to target_compile_options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282896/pass-cmake-cxx-flags-to-target-compile-options)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).